# looping over javascript that seems to be json format and changing

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I want to loop over an object in javascript that is likely json

```
{
Id: 6,
Name: 'faser',
Description: 'adsf',
Verbiage: 'asdf',
VerbiageSpanish: 'asdf',
Active: true,
directive: {
    '4': true,
    '5': true
 }
}
```

The loop I really only want to loop over `directive`  as that will be 1 to many of them.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: As there is no conversion of this javascript object to any kind of string, it's nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: JSON is a format.  That's a normal object.  Look at `Object.keys()`.

Comment: Since  "Id" etc.. and not in quotes is it not really json  ?  @SLaks

Comment: No; it's still a Javascript object literal.  JSON is just a data format that happens to look like Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but understanding your object structure is the key.

Object properties (a.k.a. keys) are just strings and those strings can be passed to an object reference to get a reference to that property.

```js
var jsonResultObject = {
Id: 6,
Name: 'faser',
Description: 'adsf',
Verbiage: 'asdf',
VerbiageSpanish: 'asdf',
Active: true,
directive: {
    '4': true,
    '5': true
 }
}

// Loop over the main object's properties
for(var d in jsonResultObject){
  // Check if the property is "directive"
  if(d === "directive"){
    // If so, loop over the properties of that object
    for(var prop in jsonResultObject[d]){
      // get the property name and its value
      console.log(prop + ":" + jsonResultObject[d][prop]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the existence of the directive property on the object, and then use `Object.keys` to loop over it if found.

```js
let obj = {
  Id: 6,
  Name: 'faser',
  Description: 'adsf',
  Verbiage: 'asdf',
  VerbiageSpanish: 'asdf',
  Active: true,
  directive: {
    '4': true,
    '5': true
  }
};

if (obj.directive) {
  Object.keys(obj.directive).forEach(key => {
    console.log(key, obj.directive[key]);
  })
}
```